# How to add a prefix to every line?

Tags: text-editing, editing

I have the code below:

```
Hello
There
I am some code
```

And want to add code in front of it, like:

```
I said Hello
I said There
I said I am some code
```

So how would I add a prefix to each line?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can add a prefix with `M-x string-rectangle`, which is bound to `C-x r t`.
This is part of a series of commands that operates on [*rectangular selections*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html); this one inserts text at every line in the rectangle.

Start by setting the mark at the beginning of the first line, and move your cursor to the *first* character of the last line you want to prefix:

```
*Hello
 There
▮I am some code
```

Then use `C-x r t`, enter your prefix (`I said`) and press `RET`. This adds the text to each line in the rectangle:

```
I said Hello
I said There
I said I am some code
```

If you don't line up your cursor on the same column as your mark, it will overwrite that part of the rectangle:

```
*Hello
 There
 I am▮ some code
```

with the same command results in:

```
I said o
I said e
I said  some code
```

Comment: you are the second person to earn [good answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) badge :)

Comment: An alternative is to use `M-x string-insert-rectangle`. It's very similar, but `string-insert-rectangle` _inserts_ at the beginning of each line of the selection, whereas `string-rectangle` _replaces_, so with the latter you have to be more precise about your selection if you don't want to overwrite anything.

Answer (score 34):

You could use [multiple-cursors-mode](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el), to put a cursor on every line.  Then, any text you type will be inserted on each line.

You would start out with the point at the beginning of the piece of code:

```
▮Hello
 There
 I am some code
```

Then hit <kbd>C-></kbd> twice.  (This is the suggested key binding; you have to set it up yourself.)  This creates two extra cursors on the following two lines:

```
▮Hello
▮There
▮I am some code
```

Then type `I said`.  The text will be added on each line:

```
I said ▮Hello
I said ▮There
I said ▮I am some code
```

Finally hit <kbd>RET</kbd> to exit multiple cursors mode and leave point at the last cursor:

```
I said Hello
I said There
I said ▮I am some code
```

[Here](http://emacsrocks.com/e13.html) is a video that shows how it works.

Answer (score 29):

Personally, I prefer `replace-regexp` (replace "^" with "I said ").

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use macros, which can handle more tasks than rectangular selections or multiple cursors, even if it's a little clunkier for this specific case.

Position the cursor at the beginning of the first line and hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to start recording, insert the text, move the cursor to the beginning of the next line and hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording. Now hit <kbd>F4</kbd> again to repeat the macro, <kbd>C-2</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat it twice, or <kbd>C-0</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat it until an error (such as running out of lines) is encountered.

Answer (score 11):

You could install [evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/Evil) and do it in any number of [vi-like ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174274/how-can-i-prepend-text-to-multiple-lines-in-vim) - I prefer visual block selection using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to mark each line and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to insert and then type the text you want to insert and finally hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit insert mode and the text will be prepended to each line. This is very similar to emacs rectangle selections but a few less keystrokes.

Answer (score 9):

This is very similar to artagnon's answer, but `replace-regexp` is not bound to any key.

So, I actually use `query-replace-regexp` which is bound by default to `C-M-%` and then replace `^` with the given prefix `I said` and then type `!` to replace all without prompting anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `cua-mode` enabled, then:

- <kbd>C-a</kbd> to move to beginning of line,
- <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to start rectangle,
- <kbd>↓</kbd> (down key) twice to move to third line,
- `I said` as text to be inserted
- <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to end rectangle

I prefer the `cua-mode` way of working, compared to the Emacs standard rectangle where the equivalent would be:

- <kbd>C-a</kbd> to move to beginning of line,
- <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> to start rectangle,
- <kbd>↓</kbd> (down key) twice to move to third line,
- <kbd>C-x r t</kbd> `I said` <kbd>RET</kbd> to insert text

The `cua-mode` saves two key presses compared to standard Emacs rectangle.

But for me, the additional advantage of cua-mode is that I can *append* text to the rectangle (I personally to do not know how to *append* text with standard Emacs rectangle). With cua-mode, it is one <kbd>RET</kbd> key press only, inputed before the `I said`.