# How to shift a selected area of text in Emacs by a certain number of spaces?

Tags: whitespace

I am writing python code so shifting/moving blocks of lines is important to avoid going through each line individually. How can I do this without an add-on? Is there a type of operation keystroke command to do this?

Comment: For non-Python-specific answers, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/11 and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use command `indent-rigidly`, which is bound to `C-x TAB` by default.

You can specify the number of spaces to indent by using a [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html), such as `C-5 C-x TAB`.

Or you can invoke the command and then use the left/right arrows to interactively adjust the indent level.

Comment: how do you add a prefix argument?

Comment: Try for example `C-5 C-x TAB` to indent the current region 5 spaces.

Comment: great, but why does the first line not move as well? I have to grab the last part of the line above the selection to make the set of lines I want move.

Comment: You shouldn't need to select anything from the previous line, but you do want to select from the beginning of the first line you want to indent. For example, `C-a` to move to the beginning of the line, `C-SPC` to start marking the region, `C-n C-n` to move down a couple lines, `C-5 C-x TAB` to indent those two lines.

Comment: "use the left/right arrows to interactively adjust the indent level" Really? Great! I didn't know this, and sometimes I had to guess how much spaces I need to add or remove. I hope this can help.

Comment: I was surprised by the interactive feature as well. It must be fairly new, I guess.

Comment: Just checked the NEWS file, the interactive behavior of `indent-rigidly` was introduced in Emacs 24.4.

Answer (score 15):

If you are used python-mode.el `C-c >` or `C-c <` to shift blocks left or right

Comment: how come the first line of the selection remains unmoved if I don't select the last part of the line above it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. all line of a selections are moved. Emacs 24.4

Comment: glucas' comment says that this will happen if you don't select from the start of the line

Answer (score 9):

The `string-rectangle` command ( `C-x r t`) can be used to insert any arbitrary text (spaces included) in a selected region.

Let's say you have this block of text and you want to insert 5 spaces in front of all lines.

```
abc
  def
    ghi
```

First select a "0 column" region as shown below (the point is on the character 'a' and the mark is in the same column in the row containing 'ghi':

```
▮bc
  def
▯   ghi
```

Now using `string-rectangle`, insert the text you want to insert in the selected region. In this example, we will be inserting 5 spaces on all the rows including and inbetween the point and the mark.

```
C-x r t M-5 SPC RET
```

That will give the below force indented text.

```
     abc
       def
         ghi
```

Answer (score 6):

There is `C-x TAB` (bound to `indent-rigidly`). Give it a prefix argument to indicate how many spaces you wish to indent by, negative removes that many spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found that by pressing Alt-4 and then SPC, I get the desired result. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works as well.